# Unix utilities, sum the data under the save entries

Tags: unix, command-line, awk, gawk

I have this little problem that I want to ask:

So I have a file named `"quest"`, which has:

> Tom 100 John 10 Tom 100

How do I use `awk` to output something like:

> Tom 200

I'd appreciate your help. I tried to look up online but I am not sure what I am look for. Thanks ahead!!

I do know how to use regular expression `/Tom/` to `grep` the entry, but I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I did give `-1` since its not clear of this is one line only, or if its only `Tom` you like to get out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$ awk '{
for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2)
    names[$i] = ((names[$i]) ? names[$i]+$(i+1) : $(i+1))
}
END{
    for (name in names) print name, names[name]
}' quest
Tom 200
John 10
```

You basically iterate over the fields creating keys for all odd fields and assigning values of even fields to them. If the key already exists, you just add to the existing value.

This expects your file format to have Names on odd fields (for eg. 1, 3, 5 .. etc) and values on even fields (eg 2, 4, 6 .. etc).

In the `END` block, you just print entire array content.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need calculate all users' mark, not only `Tom`, here is the code:

```
xargs -n2 < file|awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}'

Tom 200
John 10
```

and one-liner of awk

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) a[$i]+=$(i+1)}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file

Tom 200
John 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'Tom 100 John 10 Tom 100' | grep -o '[0-9]*' | paste -sd+ | bc
210
```

`grep -o '[0-9]*'` produces

```
100
10
100
```

`paste -sd+` produces

```
100+10+100
```

`bc` calculates the result.

However, this only works for small input since `bc` has limitation in input size.

In that case you can use `awk '{s+=$0}END{print s}'` instead of `paste -sd+ | bc`.

However note that `GNU Awk` treats all number as floting point, it produces inaccurate result when number is too large.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/Tom/{
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
     if($i=="Tom")s+=$(i+1);
     print "Tom",s;s=0}' your_file
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/d2UVxp)

Comment: I guess you get -1 since it only counts `Tom` no other name. But he asked for it, so you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it in `awk` (no loop):

```
awk -v RS=" " '{n=$1;getline;a[n]+=$1} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' quest
Tom 200
John 10
```

---

If there are more than one line like this

```
cat quest
Tom 100 John 10 Tom 100
Paul 20 Tom 40 John 10
```

Then do this with  `gnu awk`:

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" '{n=$1;getline;a[n]+=$1} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' quest
Paul 20
Tom 240
John 20
```

---

And if you do not like `getline`

```
awk -v RS=" |\n" 'NR%2 {n=$1;next}{a[n]+=$1} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' quest
```

Comment: `RS` is the *RECORD Separator*

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Do not edit the post like this (only if it has errors) If you do like to formatting, post a comment about it. And maybe the owner of the post will change it, or add both version.

Comment: Np, I would suggest that you separate each PATTERN ACTION pair into a separate line.  I tend to prefer shorter lines for readability - especially the last snippet results in a horizontal scroll bar on my screen.  Also, please explain the use of `RS` in the answer itself.